# is there a way to fix this so it doesnt destroy the body

Tags: c#

The code is a snippet of code from the torso but if you press 'f' on the torso it fires a laser. If the characters arm moves in front of the laser while it is firing it will get cut off, is there a way to fix this? PS: I'm not that good at coding. :P

```
    laser.enabled = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        var end = Physics2D.Raycast(BarrelPosition, BarrelDirection, 10000, bounds);
        var endPos = end.transform == null ? (Vector3)BarrelPosition + (Vector3)BarrelDirection * 10000 : (Vector3)end.point;
        var victimCount = Physics2D.LinecastNonAlloc(BarrelPosition, endPos, victimBuffer, layers);
        laser.SetPosition(1, components.transform.InverseTransformPoint(endPos));
    
        for (int n = 0; n < victimCount; n++)
        {
           var victim = victimBuffer[n];
           victim.transform.SendMessage("Slice", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
           // phys.rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(forward * DirectionalForce * phys.rigidbody.mass, hit.point, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    
        CameraShakeBehaviour.main.Shake(1, transform.position);
        physicalBehaviour.rigidbody.AddRelativeForce(new Vector2(0f * transform.localScale.normalized.x, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
    }
    
    laser.enabled = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
}
    
public override Vector2 BarrelPosition { get { return transform.TransformPoint(barrelPosition); } }
    
public Vector2 BarrelDirection { get { return transform.TransformDirection(barrelDirection) * transform.localScale.x; } }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend you take the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and at least skim over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then refine your question with more details afterwards.